# Too many break statements have the tendency to destructure your code

Tags: java

while reading "**Java complete reference seventh edition**" in page 100.
I read this statement "**However, be careful. Too many break statements have the tendency to destructure your code**"
What I don't understand how can **break** statement change or deconstructed in my code?
Is that in java only or in all programming languages?
Is that something linked to byte-code?
Thanx so much, please do not misunderstand me :)

Comment: "destructure" is not the same as "deconstructed"

Comment: I think he meant logically, for example tracing code for user become harder

Comment: [Are `break` and `continue` bad programming practices?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices)

Comment: No... not related to byte-code. And can happen with any programming language, not specific to Java only. That's why we have some paradigms in all programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author uses the word  **de-structure your code**. Its just an expression. what he actually meant by that is:

Imagine you writing five loops one inside another having break statements for all the loops. If the loop gets bigger and bigger, there are high chances of losing the execution path as a developer i.e. which loop is being executed and from which loop the control has **broken** out of. 
   Imagine the chaos it creates if you have more loops having break for each loop/more break statements for a few loops. The only thing that catches your eye is the **break statement** .

Answer (score 5):

> Too many break statements have the tendency to destructure your code

I believe that the author means that it is more difficult to follow the execution paths in your code. This is because `break` jumps to a line of your code that potentially can be far away from the line with the `break`.

Answer (score 0):

> However, be careful. Too many break statements have the tendency to destructure your code.

This doesn't mean that if you have a switch statement to compare over 100 unique values, then it will de-structure your code. Because, in this case, that's the only need.

But suppose, you are using too many `loops`, could be anything, `for-loop`, `while-loop`, `do-while-loop` or even `if-else` conditions, excessively using `break`statement will come out with too many **permutations and combinations** of execution path which we at development phase might not see. And then, can cause a big trouble at real time execution with multiple values or multiple types of values which may trigger a new, unexplored path of execution. (I mean, those paths, which we were not intended to create.)

So, the author says better to avoid **too many** break statements. Not all.